# how to get email from owner or from gmail account on android

Tags: android, gmail

I was wondering how to get the email from the owner of the phone or from the gmail account used on the phone.

I am trying to do this on android 1.6 and up.

I know its possible because I have seen some apps that get the email.
Maybe its undocumented or it reads it from a undocumented provider or some authentication service, but I know its possible.

Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve information from another application you would use it's content provider.

The problem with what you want to do is that the gmail application is closed source and does not have documentation like the rest of the open source SDK.  You could hack a solution together using undocumented providers like you said, but updates to the gmail application may break your code.

Either create your own email application using POP3 or IMAP and integrate with that, or think of a different way to do what you're looking to accomplish.